# How to import an artifactory repository (ie: worldwind) inside an Android project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, artifactory, worldwind

I followed the [documentation](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/android/get-started/) to import WorldWind inside my project :

> repositories {
> maven {
> url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
> } }
>
> ...
>
> compile 'gov.nasa.worldwind.android:worldwind:0.9.0-SNAPSHOT'

However it throws me this exception :

> Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
> Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Here is my **settings.gradle** file :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{ url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'}
    }
}
rootProject.name = "WorldWind"
include ':app'
```

And my **build.gradle** file :

```
...

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'gov.nasa.worldwind.android:worldwind:0.9.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: The documentation seems to be outdated. As the project is hosted on GitHub you could use jitpack.io to use the GitHub repo as artifact if you want the latest snapshot https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindAndroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the 0.8.0 version from `jcenter()`:

```kotlin
// settings.gradle
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

// app build.gradle
implementation("gov.nasa.worldwind.android:worldwind:0.8.0")
```

I think the repository has been [discontinued](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/).